# Can Bose QC 15 block out traffic noise when you are cycling?

Tags: noise-cancelling

Has anyone tried using Bose QC 15 or 25 while cycling? I ride my bike every day and am wondering if it will be able to block out the traffic noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same headphones (QC 15) and they are excellent at filtering all typical noise. The pass band is tight, about 500HZ to 3KHZ, which is why even voices sound 'tinny'.
 What they cannot block well is very deep bass, like a kick-drum or something heavy being dropped, or a gun-shot, but they do reduce the volume of such loud noises at least a little bit.
 They block at least 90% of airplane and traffic noise, especially horns, but pot-holes can be heard if you hit a deep one. You would feel it as well I'm sure. They are excellent noise blockers, allowing only vocals to pass through.
 **NOTE**: Extensive heat (including sweat) for long periods can make the soft ear pads come loose.